# PHP генерирование значений при выполнение консольной команды

Tags: php

Нашел в [документации PHP](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.shell-exec.php) информацию о том, что есть возможность выполнять консольные команды из веб-страницы.

Итак, я хочу выполнить консольную команду, к примеру:

```
ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -r 30 -t {time} -bufsize 2000000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 videoID_date_time.mp4.
```

Мне нужно заменить `{time}` - на время записи, `ID` - на случайное число, `date` - на дату на компьютере и `time` - на время на компьютере соответственно.

Я не силен в PHP поэтому прошу пояснить подробнее.

Comment: Что вы сделали для решения проблемы? С чем столкнулись?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php

Comment: моя проблема в том, что не понимаю как это написать. Даже прочитав мануал. Нужен более наглядный пример от гуру.

Comment: там же есть пример, создайте форму ввода на странице, а в функцию передавайте значение из поля формы и выводите результат

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$time = escapeshellarg($time);
`ffmpeg -i - -vcodec copy -an -r 30 -t $time -bufsize 2000000 -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mp4 videoID_date_time.mp4`;
```

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php